# Understanding turbostat debug mode max turbo output

Tags: linux, performance, intel, turbo

Does the output of running turbostat --debug show max turbo per core per socket?
below is an example output. If I have say a 2 socket Server does that mean 2 active cores per Socket can boost to 4GHz (4 cores total) or over both sockets - so only 1 core per socket=2 cores in total?

```
cpu0: MSR_NHM_TURBO_RATIO_LIMIT: 0x25262727
37 * 100 = 3700 MHz max turbo 4 active cores
38 * 100 = 3800 MHz max turbo 3 active cores
39 * 100 = 3900 MHz max turbo 2 active cores
40 * 100 = 4000 MHz max turbo 1 active cores
```

I also presume a core here is made up of 2 cpu's I.e a dual socket 20 core machine has 40 cpu's per socket?

Any help is much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: This question would probably be a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Turbo limits are per-package (i.e. socket), based on number of physical cores that are currently not in sleep states *on that socket*.  e.g. 4GHz if running a single-threaded program (and the system's otherwise idle), or 3.7 GHz if all physical cores are busy.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "2 socket CPU".  A CPU is something that goes in a physical socket on a motherboard.  It can have multiple *cores*, but a multi-socket motherboard will have multiple CPUs (if it's fully populated).

Comment: Thanks Peter - "turbo limits are per-package" this is the answer I was looking for. Sorry I miss worded the question and I am aware of a what a dual/quad socket motherboard is - was the end of a long day.